# Get object property with colon on Yii active record

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii. Relational active record returned this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Authitem Object
    (
        [_md:CActiveRecord:private] => 
        [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
        [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [name] => admin
                [type] => 2
                [description] => 
                [bizrule] => 
                [data] => 
            )

        [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
        [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => admin
        [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
        [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_validators:CModel:private] => 
        [_scenario:CModel:private] => update
        [_e:CComponent:private] => 
        [_m:CComponent:private] => 
    )

)
```

How do i get array from [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private]? I already tried authMenus[0]->[_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] and authMenus[0]->_attributes but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly access like so:

```
$authMenus[0]->attributes;
// or in general
$array_of_active_record_objects[index]->attributes;
$array_of_active_record_objects[index]->single_attribute;
```

Because CActiveRecord has a [custom getter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#__get-detail).

Comment: geez! i didn't expect it to be this simple.

Comment: how did you know I was looking for that? :) thanks for the update.